# nicedit - is it safe and is it affected by the site's css?

Tags: nicedit

I'm considering using nicedit (http://nicedit.com/) for my site.

I assume that nicedit simply creates simple html using the buttons, and that html gets sent when the user saves it.

1. Is it recommended? Is someone still working on it?
2. Assuming I'm later displaying this HTML in my site somewhere, isn't it dangerous due to the user being able to plant malicious javascript? If not, how does nicedit prevents this?
3. Also, when I display this HTML later, will it be affected by my css? If so, how can I prevent this?

Thanks.

Comment: 2) You should always filter the HTML anyways because any user could inject invalid values. Just allow the tags `<b>`, `<i>`, `<u>`, `<font>`, etc. without any inappropraite attributes.

Comment: @minitech are you sure nicedit doesn't escape them already?

Comment: Probably not - but it doesn't matter. Injection is possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use it works like a charm for cleaning out the content of the nicedit instance before chucking into the database

```
function cleanFromEditor($text) { 

    //try to decode html before we clean it then we submit to database
    $text = stripslashes(html_entity_decode($text));

    //clean out tags that we don't want in the text
    $text = strip_tags($text,'<p><div><strong><em><ul><ol><li><u><blockquote><br><sub><img><a><h1><h2><h3><span><b>');

    //conversion elements
    $conversion = array(
        '<br>'=>'<br />',
        '<b>'=>'<strong>',
        '</b>'=>'</strong>',
        '<i>'=>'<em>',
        '</i>'=>'</em>'
    );

    //clean up the old html with new
    foreach($conversion as $old=>$new){
        $text = str_replace($old, $new, $text);
    }   

    return htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($text));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. It doesn't appear to be maintained anymore. But I have used it for purposes where I needed just a simple/lightweight WYSIWYG editor. If you are looking for something that gets constant core updates or additional features I wouldn't count on it. I finally broke down and wrote a lot of my own features like tables and YouTube videos.
2. Yes, a hacker could use it to post an client and/or server exploit on your site. But this is a threat you can face with any editor. You need to filter the code for two methods.

You need to prevent SQL injection by sanitizing your post variables. I always put this at the beginning of my scripts to clean them and call them with `$input['whateveryouarepassing']`instead of `$_POST['whateveryouarepassing']`. Edit the `$mysqli->real_escape_string()` parts to work with your database object. Use MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements to help harden the attack.

```
$input = array();

if(isset($_POST)) {

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if (@get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

            $key = stripslashes($key);

            $value = stripslashes($value);

        }

        $key = $mysqli->real_escape_string($key);

        $value = $mysqli->real_escape_string($value);

        $input[$key] = $value;

    }

}
```

Then I like to clean it with this function I put together over the years with various methods of cleaning out bad code. Use HTML Purifier instead if you can set it up. If not, here is this bad boy. Call it with `cleanHTML($input['whateveryouarepassing']);`.

```
function cleanHTML($string) {

    $string = preg_replace('#(&\#*\w+)[\x00-\x20]+;#u', "$1;", $string);

    $string = preg_replace('#(&\#x*)([0-9A-F]+);*#iu', "$1$2;", $string);

    $string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");

    $string = preg_replace('#(<[^>]+[\x00-\x20\"\'\/])(on|xmlns)[^>]*>#iUu', "$1>", $string);

    $string = preg_replace('#([a-z]*)[\x00-\x20\/]*=[\x00-\x20\/]*([\`\'\"]*)[\x00-\x20\/]*j[\x00-\x20]*a[\x00-\x20]*v[\x00-\x20]*a[\x00-\x20]*s[\x00-\x20]*c[\x00-\x20]*r[\x00-\x20]*i[\x00-\x20]*p[\x00-\x20]*t[\x00-\x20]*:#iUu', '$1=$2nojavascript...', $string);

    $string = preg_replace('#([a-z]*)[\x00-\x20\/]*=[\x00-\x20\/]*([\`\'\"]*)[\x00-\x20\/]*v[\x00-\x20]*b[\x00-\x20]*s[\x00-\x20]*c[\x00-\x20]*r[\x00-\x20]*i[\x00-\x20]*p[\x00-\x20]*t[\x00-\x20]*:#iUu', '$1=$2novbscript...', $string);

    $string = preg_replace('#([a-z]*)[\x00-\x20\/]*=[\x00-\x20\/]*([\`\'\"]*)[\x00-\x20\/]*-moz-binding[\x00-\x20]*:#Uu', '$1=$2nomozbinding...', $string);

    $string = preg_replace('#([a-z]*)[\x00-\x20\/]*=[\x00-\x20\/]*([\`\'\"]*)[\x00-\x20\/]*data[\x00-\x20]*:#Uu', '$1=$2nodata...', $string);

    $string = preg_replace('#(<[^>]+[\x00-\x20\"\'\/])style[^>]*>#iUu', "$1>", $string);

    $string = preg_replace('#</*\w+:\w[^>]*>#i', "", $string);

    $string = preg_replace('/^<\?php(.*)(\?>)?$/s', '$1', $string);

    $string = preg_replace('#</*(applet|meta|xml|blink|link|script|embed|object|frame|iframe|frameset|ilayer|layer|bgsound|title|base)[^>]*>#i', "", $string);

    return $string;

}
```

1. The HTML will be affected by your CSS when editing and displayed. You will need code additional CSS rules if this is an issue. If the issue is when editing move to a iframe based editor and to prevent the css display the html content in an iframe.
2. If you want another suggestion elRTE is my goto editor these days. A little more advanced but totally worth it once you get to know the code base and API. You will face the same issues as above as will any editor. Except the CSS during editing since elRTE is framebased and you can specify stylesheets. [elRTE Homepage](http://elrte.org/)

Edit: I posted this assuming you were using PHP. Apologies if not.